# Verbose messages at system start

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel

In 14.04 after adding `VERBOSE_INIT=YES` to `linux` line in Grub it was possible to enable verbose messages at system boot. In 14.10 this trick doesn't work any more. Removing `quiet` argument from `linux` line in Grub also doesn't work.

How to enable verbose boot messages in 14.10???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a file `/etc/grub.d/10_linux` that is needed to generate GRUB configuration. At the top of file are configuration variables. Only thing to do is change `vt_handoff` value to `0`. Here is like it looks like after changes:

```
prefix="/usr"
exec_prefix="/usr"
datarootdir="/usr/share"
ubuntu_recovery="1"
quiet_boot="1"
quick_boot="1"
gfxpayload_dynamic="1"
vt_handoff="0"
```

In file `/etc/default/grub` remove `quiet` from `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` line.

At the end generate grub configuration.

```
update-grub
```